# Django - Get counts of objects in related sets

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

There are two models:

```
class Article(..:
    locations = ManyToMany('Location'...,related_name='articles')

class Location(...):
    ...
```

I'm looking for a way to get number of location appearance in any related_set `Article.locations`

For example:

1. Article1 - Milan, Vienna, Paris
2. Article2 - Milan, Paris
3. Article3 - Paris
4. Article  - Dubai

The result would be:

Paris - 3, Milan - 2, Vienna - 1, Dubai -1

I ended with this:

```
Location.objects.all().annotate(Count(?))
```

Is it possible to do it in one or two `Queries`? I want to avoid doing it using loops.

Moreover, I want to do it considering only subset of `Articles` (filtered queryset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Location.objects.all().annotate(
    locations_count=Count('locations')
  )
```

and in template

```
{{obj.locations_count}}
```

or

```
ax = Location.objects.all().count()
 {{ax}}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer, related_name is articles. And do you have an Idea how to make it work on subset of articles?

Comment: And I think your outer Count() doesn't make sense, there should be only Count('locations') if I understand correctly.